# What type can't be copied in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I was passing through interview, and there was a question I couldn't answer.

What objects can't be copied (property `copy`) in objective C.
And specific details on copy property.

I've looked through web, but didn't find the information about it.
Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **copyable** objects in objective c, which confirm to the `NSCopying` and `NSSecureCoding` protocols. All the object those don't confirm to these protocols, are not copyable. Hope, this clears things out.

P.S.: There is `NSMutableCopying` protocol for copying mutable version of the object as well.

Comment: Yep, don't forget to accept the answer, if it solves your issue, cheers!

Comment: This is the right answer. Objects that don't conform to `NSCopying` can't be copied. See the note at [Copy Properties Maintain Their Own Copies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW35).

Answer (score 0):

Depending what they meant in the interview question, there are objects that accept the copy method but don't return a copy, but return the same object with increased reference count. For example immutable strings, arrays, NSNumber and so on.

Comment: True, and I know you mean that these objects can't *actually* be copied, but the fact that `-copy` returns the original object for immutable objects is an implementation detail. As far as the caller is concerned, the object has been copied. But since the OP specifically talks about the `copy` property attribute, it's far more important that some objects will throw an exception if you send them a `-copy` message.